# json will not be be deserialized to an appropriate model?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I have this json

```
[
            {
               "internalName": "a"
            }
          ]
```

And a model

```
public class UC
{
    public string InternalName { get; set; }
}
```

which was generated from [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io?share=yqGVnuWpV3mDWGQSSalT)

but I cannot seem to deserialize this using `system.text.json`?

this is triggering is causing an error

```
UC u = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UC>(json)
```

Comment: Think you're missing the attribute `[JsonProperty("internalName")]`, mind the casing.

Comment: Additionally, your JSON represents a *list* rather than a single item.

Comment: @JonSkeet the list only contain one property. 
I have done this with others.. this is the only one which need this?

Comment: @kafka: Sure, it only contains one object, but it's still a list. Once you've added the `JsonProperty` attribute (because System.Text.Json is case-sensitive) you should try deserializing to `List<UC>`. You should end up with a list containing a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json string represents array not a single object, try `var us = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<UC>>(json)`

Also do not forget to mark property with `[JsonPropertyName("internalName")]` attribute as stated in the comments(or via `JsonSerializerOptions` as you mentioned yourself ☺️).